# Getting Image Element by Class and ID Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that displays images in a certain arrangement to reflect a wafer. When the user clicks an image, a red border is placed around it. This image id is then saved in a cookie array and when the page is reloaded those particular images need to keep their border.

My problem is I am unable to access the html element using the id.

For instance this:

```
$("#10.3_6").css('border', "solid 2px red");
```

does not work. This is how I put on the border:

```
$("tr.smallthumbs a img").click(function() {
        var found = 0;
        for(var j in array){
            if(this.id == array[j]){
                found = j+1;
                break;
            };
        };

        if(found == 0){ 
            $(this).css('border', "solid 2px blue");    
            array.push(this.id); 
            console.log(this)
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('border', "solid 2px white");
            array.splice(found-1,1)

        };
        $.cookie('activePixels',array);
});
```

This puts a red border around all the images.

```
$("tr.smallthumbs a img").css('border', "solid 2px red");
```

How can I access just one by its id?

Thanks!

Comment: you probably need to escape the period in your ID

Comment: Your life will be a lot, lot easier if you don't put special characters that must be escaped into your id or class names.  Avoid most punctuation characters.

Comment: It's an inherent name of the images I'm displaying, so I didn't want to rename them. However, I will make sure to avoid it in the future.

Comment: you can use $("[id='10.3_6']")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector

```
$("#10.3_6")
```

means the element with `id="10"` and `class="3_6"`. If you want to access an element with `id="10.3_6"` you need to escape the `.`:

```
$("#10\\.3_6")
```

It would be a good idea to use a different naming scheme for your IDs, since `.` has this special meaning in selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `.`. `.` indicates the class selector, so the selector you have used looks for an element with id `10` and cass `3_6`

```
$("#10\\.3_6").css('border', "solid 2px red");
```

See [How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)